# Read-only file system in Telegraf and influxDB - EKS in AWS

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, telegraf, amazon-eks

I am new to Kubernetes and Influx so there is a big chance that there are things that I just didn't understood correct .

I managed to deploy influxDB and Telegraf to my cluster in EKS (AWS) but now I am trying to edit the Telegraf configuration so that I can get some input data from Kafka and store them to InfluxDB .
 My problem is that I cannot edit any file in the system or create a new configuration file . 
For example when I try to edit the config file 
`vi /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf`

I get the `Read-only file system` error . 

I read that the systems are read-only in the newest Kubernetes version but there has to be some workaround to solve this issue.

 My Kubernetes version is :

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.7", GitCommit:"8fca2ec50a6133511b771a11559e24191b1aa2b4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:47:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.6-eks-5047ed", GitCommit:"5047edce664593832e9b889e447ac75ab104f527", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-21T22:32:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and I obviously run everything with admin rights. 
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use `$ sudo vi /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` or just change file permission `$ sudo chmod 750` ?

Comment: The pod system doesnt include `sudo` but I tried with ```su``` and ```chmod 750 /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf``` and I get the usual error ```chmod: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf: Read-only file system```

Comment: Without your Pod YAML we have no way of _guessing_ what your setup is; however, it sounds like you have volume mounted a `ConfigMap` or a `Secret` into your Pod, and if either of those are true, you cannot edit those files that are volume mounted